# Problems with adding reference to netstandard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I changed my Asp.Net Core 1.1 application to Core 2.0

This went pretty well but after I updated my nuget packages and I get this error everywhere

> The type 'xxx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

When I press the button to add an assembly nothing happens. I tried rebuilding and restoring my packages multiple times but it won't work

Comment: please share the csproj to allow diagnosing the problem

Comment: Clearly Microsoft has a guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I don't know exactly what it is, but I could fix it by creating a new DotnetCore 2 project, and copy the csproj nodes

Comment: Check your csproj and remove <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion> tag if it exists.

Comment: Try to remove <RuntimeFrameworkVersion> from .csproj if it exists. 
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/860 look for the answer by @qqbuby

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925484/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are having problem with the reference to the old NETStandard version in your class library. 
Just make sure you have removed NETStandard reference from all the csproj files in the solution.

Comment: For us newbies, please explain how to do this?

Comment: Manually edit the .csproj file and add the following reference:

<Reference Include="netstandard" />

Save the project file reload the project in VS and rebuild it to see the change.