# Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard' or one of its dependencies

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, .net-framework-version, elasticsearch.net

I upgraded my solutions ElasticSearch.net and nest library to 7.1.0 version.
After deploying the code I am getting below error:

```
BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +225
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +110
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48
```

i tried copying the library to the server i deployed but that doesn't work.

Upgrade Details:
1.)ElasticSearch.net 5.6.1 to 7.1.0

2.)Nest 5.6.1 to 7.1.0

3.) .NetFramework 4.7.3 installed

4.) VS2017

upgraded from nuget package manager.

Comment: Did you try to remove bin directory from the server before deploying latest version?

Comment: Some more context around framework (Desktop CLR, Core CLR), version, environment (security permissions), steps you followed to upgrade (what version from), would help in better framing your question

Comment: as elasticsearch.net has a dependency on NETStandard.Library 2.0, I added this library. Do i have to add NETStandard.Library.NETFramework?

Comment: @Rob.yes I tried that

Comment: What framework version is project targeting? You mention `.NetFramework 4.7.3 installed`, but is that what your project is targeting?

Comment: Project is targeting 4.7 version

Answer (score 2):

The issue got resolved by manually adding the reference of netstandard library in csproj file like below:

```
<Reference Include="netstandard">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

The above workaround is provided from - [You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925484/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0)