# Not able to add reference to MetadataReference of CSharpCompilation in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want create runtime class but when use attribute [StiAlias("id")] from Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary;
send error :

[0] = (1,101): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

```
public object CreateClassRunTime()
    {
        string strClass = 
            @"using System; " +
        //"using System.Collections.Generic;" +
        "using Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary;" +

              "namespace VModel { public class AddressViewTest { " +
          "[StiAlias(\"id\")]" +
          "public int id { get; set; }" +
        
         " public int? updUser { get; set; } } }";


        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(strClass);
        string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        var refPaths = new[] {
            typeof(object).Assembly.Location,
            typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute).Assembly.Location,
            typeof(System.Runtime.AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute).Assembly.Location,
            typeof(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo).Assembly.Location,
            typeof(Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiAliasAttribute).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
           
        };
        MetadataReference[] references = refPaths.Select(r => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(r)).ToArray();

        
        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            assemblyName,
            syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
            references: references,
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
        object instance = null;
        try
        {
            byte[] image = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    Console.Write(result.Diagnostics.First().GetMessage());
                }
                image = ms.ToArray();
                //Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(ms);
                
                //instance = assembly.CreateInstance("VModel.AddressViewTest");
            }
            Assembly assembly = null;

            
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(image))
                assembly = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(stream);
            //var type = assembly.GetType("VModel.AddressViewTest");
            instance = assembly.CreateInstance("VModel.AddressViewTest");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

is solved error by ad :

```
var ns = Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51");
```

and ad to references :

```
var refPaths = new[] {
            ns.Location,
            typeof(object).Assembly.Location,...
```

}

Comment: Please check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925484/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
not worked .asp.net core 3.1 compatible with netstandard 2.0.0

Comment: is solved with this change : var ns = Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51");
            var refPaths = new[] {
                ns.Location,
                typeof(object).Assembly.Location,
                
            };

Comment: You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is solved error by add :

```
var ns = Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51");
```

and ad to references :

```
var refPaths = new[] {
        ns.Location,
        typeof(object).Assembly.Location,...}
```