# Where do you find the csproj file in a script task inside SSIS?

Tags: c#, ssis, .net-standard

We are trying to convert a C# console app to a SSIS Script task using the CsvHelper.dll, which we did register in the GAC successfully, but keep getting to this error, and there is nowhere I can find in the SSIS project to add a reference to the netstandard 2.1.0.0 assembly:

Assembly 'CsvHelper' with identity 'CsvHelper, Version=27.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823' uses 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'netstandard' with identity 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Please help, any ideas are welcome.

[Add a reference to assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925484/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0)

Comment: are you trying to use `csvhelper` in the script component or task? if you did register in the GAC, you could find `Reference` after opening the script in the solution explorer. then calling CSVhelper would not give you the error