# Application target problems. netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0 vs .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net

I have a large solution consisting of hundreds of projects.

I need to update to a new version of one of the 3rd party libraries we use.  The updated version of the library has a dependency on netstandard.

Most/all of the individual projects in the solution target .NETFramework 4.7.2

In order to get the 2 projects that are directly dependent on the 3rd party library to compile, I had to manually edit their .csproj files and add

```
<Reference Include="netstandard" />
```

Now, this got those projects to compile, however it seemed to create a downstream dependency on netstandard in every other project (~40) that referenced the two that directly reference the library.  Seemingly I could manually edit all 40 of those .csproj files, but that would probably just push the dependency up another level, and manually editing 2 .csproj files already felt wrong.

Is there a clean solution here that I'm missing?

Comment: "In order to get the 2 projects that are directly dependent on the 3rd party library to compile, I had to manually edit their .csproj files and add", why? .NET Framework 4.7.2 projects can consume .NET Standard 2.0 libraries (unless you were still using NuGet `packages.config`).

Comment: I was following an answer in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925484/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0

Comment: Then why didn't you follow the most voted answer to switch to PackageReference? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51743098/11182

Comment: I can take a closer look at that.. 
It's a decade+ old solution with over 175 projects in it so I was looking for minimal changes.