# Error CS0012 The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have two projects that both reference a local project in the same solution named Morris.Moxy, both of these apps are .NET 7.

When I compile my Domain project, Morris.Moxy and Domain both compile okay.

When I compile my Client project, Morris.Moxy gives the error...

> Error CS0012 The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is
> not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
> Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.Morris.Moxy

Why does it compile okay for Domain but not for Client?

Morris.Moxy is a Roslyn code generator, targeting .Net standard 2.0, and both projects reference it in the same way...

`<ProjectReference Include="SomePath\Morris.Moxy.csproj"  OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />`

Comment: They're _exactly_ the same type of project? Maybe compare the csproj files? P.s. why aren't you using `<PackageReference Include="Morris.Moxy" Version="1.2.0" />`? edit, oh wait, you're the author haha.

Comment: We also sometimes run into this when adding new project dependencies. But sometimes it's just visual studio. Have you tried [deleting the 'bin' and 'obj' directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706715)?

Comment: I used the cleanup tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go and clean up the bin/obj folders in the Morris.Moxy project.  It's in a completely different path (because I am hunting a bug) and so the `cleanup` tool wasn't cleaning that down along with my solution's projects' folders.

The `Domain` project is a `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` and the `Client` project is a `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly`, so this may have had something to do with it.

Comment: glad you found it :)